# When calling API I get Error 406 and CORS errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently working on a project to help my employer track shipping loads, customers, carriers, and locations, the frontend is a react app that allows users to input info about loads, customers, etc, the backend is an express server and a MySQL database. I'm using cPanels Node.js Application GUI to set up the express server but when I attempt to test the API routes in Insomnia I get a return with an Error-406. When I open my Network tab to check the routes I do get CORS issues.

This came up when I was attempting to troubleshoot why my API routes weren't being hit which lead to a "hello worlds" response after changing some of the routes, I started to get the 406 Error followed by the CORS errors in my network tab.[Insomnia API test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxXcX.png) [Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJraH.png)

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");
const mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();
// const inputCheck = require("./utils/inputCheck");

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://myURL.com",
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  credentials: true,
  content: "plain/text",
};

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();


const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/key.pem", "utf8");
const certificate = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/cert.pem", "utf8");

const credentials = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
  
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

//middleware
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());


const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  port: 3306,
  connectionLimit: 10,
});

// Attempt to connect to the database
db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to the database:", err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Connected to PHPmyAdmin Database!");

  // Release the connection when done with it
  connection.release();
});

// Add an error event handler for the pool
db.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Database error:", err);
  // You can choose to handle the error here or restart the server, etc.
});
```

Here is how my express server set up.

In my research on this, I read that it could be with how the header is set up but couldn't find exactly what I would need to set the header as.

I've tried to reset my SSL cert and key through cPanels free basic SSL, and adjusted ports.
I've verified my credentials and can log into the database.
I checked on my mod security, tried disabling it with customer services help, and reenabled it, since this is my first real experience with cPanel and didnt want to majorly mess something up.
Ive deleted and set up the Node.js application, and made sure my server.js file is in the right spot in the file manager and verified the .htaccess file, and got the ports put in there. I tried adding a false/true statement in my route:

```
//get all customers
app.get("/allcustomers", (req, res) => {
  const sql = `SELECT * FROM customers;`;
  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if(err) return res.json({Status: false, Error: "Error performing the query"})
    return res.json({Status: true, Result: result})
})
});
```

Handler on Front end

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://myURL.com/allcustomers")
      .then(result => {
        if(result.data.Status === true) {
          console.log(result.data.Status);
          setCustomerData(result.data.Result);
        } else {
          alert(result.data.Error)
        }
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, []);
```

I have not tried to set up the response and request headers which I think could be an option here.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! cPanel has been a beast to try and learn

Answer (score 0):

Modify cors setting to

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://your-react-app-domain.com",
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  credentials: true,
};
```

and modify customer function

```
app.get("/allcustomers",async (req, res) => {
    try { 
      const sql = `SELECT * FROM customers;`;
      const customers = await db.query(sql)
      const acceptHeader = req.headers["accept"];
        if (acceptHeader === "application/json") {
          return res.status(200).json(customers);
        } else if (acceptHeader === "text/plain") {
          return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(customers));
        } else {
          return res.status(406).send("Not Acceptable");
        }

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error performing the query" });
    }
});
```